# cd to original location when recording session with "script" command

Tags: bash, shell, pwd, typescript

I have `script log.txt` in my bash profile; that creates a new sub process and records my entire session to log.txt. When I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a new terminal usually this will open one in the same directory that the command was called; however, the new script sub process always reverts to the home directory.

Is there a way to "pass" the current directory to this script command somehow?

Comment: I assume you are using Mac OS X, since you mention "Cmd T"?

Comment: correct... although a system agnostic solution that works in bash would be ideal

Comment: If all you want is the scrollback history...you know you can simply print it to PDF with Cmd-P?  Or save the text-only output (no color) with Cmd-S.

Comment: You should use a different script log file for each terminal, otherwise they'll all be writing to the same log file at the same time.   If OS X has `tty` (it probably does, it's from GNU `coreutils`), you can use something like this: `script "log$(tty | sed -e 's:/:-:g').txt"`.  I have no idea what the tty device names look like on a Mac, but on a Linux system, that would produce log file names like `log-dev-pts-2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like MacOS's Terminal has a feature where it extracts the current working directory from the process running in one tab (using `/proc` or similar) and uses it as the initial current working directory for a new tab.

In this case, the process running in the first tab is `script` — which never bothers to change its current working directory, so new tabs always come up with that directory. Only the current working directory of (some) child process of `script` is actually changing, but the Terminal application is paying no attention to that.

If this is correct, then there is no workaround short of changing either how the Terminal application works or changing how `script` works.

Comment: This sounds about right.... Could it be possible then to change the parent process's CWD to mirror the child's CWD (script in this case) so that they stay in sync?

Comment: That's what I meant by "changing how `script` works". To wit, `script` would have to have this feature where it watches its child process' cwd continuously and changes its own to match. Even then it would be a hack because there's be a delay until `script` noticed its child's cwd had changed and updated its own, and it wouldn't be portable because there's no portable way to check the cwd of another process. Due to those drawbacks, I would not expect that such a new feature would be accepted for `script`.

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is simply:

```
CWD="$(pwd)" ; 
echo "PWD === ${CWD}" ;
```

Alternatively you may also in-line pass this eg:

```
CWD="something" ./script log.txt
```

The contents of the script containing:

```
cat script
#!/bin/bash
if [ $CWD ] ; then echo "CWD Preset & == ${CWD}" ; else echo "CWD NOT SET... SETTING to: $(pwd)" ; CWD=$(pwd) ; fi ;
```

You can obviously `export` the above mentioned `CWD` variable as well in which case it ought to be accessible to any other sub-shell / process.

```
export CWD="$(pwd)" ;  # or the path of interest
# ... then post New Terminal / Session:
echo "CWD == ${CWD}" ;
```